# Move to different anchor tags depending on total score

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple choice questions and depending on the progressive score, users need to move to different questions. For example, each question has 4 answers, each with a score.

```
Question 1
Answer 1 = 5 points
Answer 2 = 10 points
Answer 3 = 15 points
Answer 4 = 20 points

Question 2
Answer 1 = 5 points
Answer 2 = 10 points
Answer 3 = 15 points
Answer 4 = 20 points
```

The conditions are set in the backend where I can say if the total score is 25 then go to question 7 otherwise if any other score other than 25, proceed to the next question ie: question 3.

I am just using anchor tags to move between the questions. Where I get tripped up is if you look in the LOGIC bit below. The jump to logic requires the current score to compare to. To pinpoint the line, it is this one:

```
 <?php if( get_field( 'go_to' )  && get_sub_field( 'score' ) == // CURRENT SCORE): ?>
```

The current score changes every time a user clicks on a radio button choice.

```
$().ready(function(){
function calcscore(){
    var score = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
        score+=parseInt($(this).val());
    });  
}
    $(".calc").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php if ($questions->have_posts() ):
            while ($questions->have_posts() ): $questions->the_post();

?>
<!--Show Question-->
   <div class="question-container" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="question">
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>


        <!-- Show answers-->

        <?php if (have_rows( 'answers' ) ):
                while (have_rows( 'answers' ) ): the_row();
        ?>
            <input type="radio" name="input<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" id="input<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" value="<?php echo get_sub_field( 'score' ); ?>" class="calc">
            <label for="input<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>"><?php echo get_sub_field( 'answer' ); ?></label>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>



        <!--logic-->
        <?php if (have_rows( 'condition' ) ):
                    while (have_rows( 'condition' ) ): the_row();

        ?>     
            <?php if( get_field( 'go_to' )  && get_sub_field( 'score' ) == // CURRENT SCORE): ?>
             <a href="#<?php echo get_field( 'go_to' )->ID; ?>" class="next-btn">Next</a>
            <?php else: ?>
             <a href="#<?php echo get_the_ID() + 1; ?>" class="next-btn">Next</a>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!--end logic-->


        <!-- end show answers-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Question-->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: "*Where I get tripped up is if you look in the LOGIC bit below.*"  Tripped up how?  What is/should be happening or not happening?

Comment: It's checking if a value on the server is = to the total score. But the total score changes every time a radio button is checked, however that server side code only runs once when the page is rendered so that check will not actually ever work?

Comment: Maybe this logic, then, should be in the JS and not reliant on the PHP?

Comment: Yes, agreed. Just trying to figure out how to actually do that in the JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this in JavaScript.  You already have a JS function that runs every time an answer is clicked.  Within this function, you have an `each` that loops on each `radio` button...

```
$(".calc:checked").each(function(){...}
```

And the radio button names are connected to the anchor names, right?  *Let's use that connection!*  So try adding in this...

```
if(this.prop('checked')) { // we only care about ANSWERED questions
    var newanchorlink = 'input' + parseInt($(this).attr('name').replace('input', ''), 10) + 1;
    $('.next-btn').attr('href', '#' + newanchorlink);
}
```

You should see what is happening here: your radio buttons have property `name="input(SOMENUMBER)"`, so, I take that property, replace "input" with "", parsing it as an integer, add 1 to it, and concatting it with the word "input".  The second thing I'm doing is just changing the href to link to our new URL.

This will only work, though, under various conditions: your inputs are incremental, i.e., `input1`, `input2`, etc..  Your inputs must have the `name` property of `input(somenumber)`, it would not work on a `nextinput(somenumber)`.  Also, we are checking that something is answered by means of it being last in the input list satisfying the condition `prop('checked')`, and this will need recoding if you change the orders or use other inputs.

Granted, I did not test this myself!  There is a lot going on here, a bit much for making a demo.  But I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to make sure we are on the same page here. The condition is coming from the server ie: if the total score is 25, jump ahead to question 5, otherwise jump to the next question in all other cases. So, when the radio button is checked, it calculates the score and that value needs to be compared to the server value and from there the something happens based on that

Comment: Try this: Change `if(this.prop('checked'))` to `if(this.prop('checked') && server.query('yourqueryargs'))`.  If you need to control this based on the server's responses, this will still give you the front-end JS changes, but will be reliant on your server query.  You can make a "`server`" var by means of `new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed explanation of your algorithm, something that isn't done often enough.

Comment: I think I have figured it out now, thanks for all your help and explanation! I have another question now but will ask in a separate question.

Comment: Excellent, glad to have been of help!